# WWE '13 Universe Draft Mode

Tags: wwe-13

I'm currently playing through the WWE 2013 Universe Mode for the XBOX 360. Draft Mode is enabled and I just played through one-year of playthrough for the "season" but haven't been presented with any sort of "Draft Day" or similar activities.

How do you start the Draft mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `Edit Your Show` (where you can change your title belts), at the bottom you can turn draft on and off.

Only two shows can draft at the same time. If you have three shows drafting then it won't work.

Comment: So if I make a third show, I'd have to disable RAW or Smackdown's Draft day?